# MYSQL 8 JPA 2.0 mysql adds 1 seconds to current date after JPA save

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jboss, jboss6.x

I migrated mysql version from 5.5.40 to 8.0.18. After migration, I changed By JBoss 6 datasource configuration for driver class.

```
        <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
```

I have put mysql-connector-java-8.0.18 to lib folder.  Then my applications is deployed to Jboss 6 without problem. When I start to test application, I have found something. Regarding to Simulation Job entity,  I set startDateTime column
a date. After  simulation job is saved to database, startDateTime is different from one which I set. But there is only **one second** difference. For example İf I set date to 2019-11-08 15:20:12, Database stores it 2019-11-08 15:20:13. I am not sure this is related to timezone. But anyway I changed time zone of mysql using following statement.

SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "SIMULATION_JOB")
public class SimulationJob implements Serializable {
/**
 *
 */
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -1768265008703114922L;

public SimulationJob() {
    super();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "SimulationJobIdGen")
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
@Column(name = "NAME")
@NotNull
@Size(max = 50)
private String name;
@Column(name = "PRIORITY")
private int priority;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_USER_ID")
private User ownerUser;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATE_DATETIME")
private Date createDateTime;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "START_DATETIME")
private Date startDateTime;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "END_DATETIME")
private Date endDateTime;
```

}

Comment: Those `2019-11-08-15-20-12` and `2019-11-08-15-20-13.` *"datetime"* formats look odd?  This `2019-11-08 14:04:01` datetime format in MySQL is a valid format example..

Comment: But I need also seconds

Comment: *"But I need also seconds"* Yea i forgot to add the seconds to the example, i was just intime to update that comment..

Comment: actualy I put format from SimpleDateFormatçMysql stores it 2019-11-08 15:20:13

Comment: *" For example İf I set date to 2019-11-08 15:20:12, Database stores it 2019-11-08 15:20:13. I am not sure this is related to timezone"* I would just change that insert that MySQL's `NOW()` is used in the SQL query, but unsure how to do this used jpa of that is even possible..  Or simply `alter` the table with a `DEFAULT current_timestamp()` on that column and dont set it in jpa.. Besides that i didn't program in Java for a long time so i do not know why it happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it may have to do with rounding of timestamp. Before MySQL 5.6.4 the handling of fractional seconds (i.e. milliseconds) was different.

See also:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: I tried to set this. But it did not work.SET @@sql_mode = sys.list_add(@@sql_mode, 'TIME_TRUNCATE_FRACTIONAL');

Comment: You can specifiy it directly when defining your schema:

       CREATE TABLE t1 (dt DATETIME(0));

0 means no fractions.

Comment: But it will round if I use no fractions? the problem it always adds one second to one which I set.

Comment: Then try it with 6 digits precision which will keep all microseconds without rounding.